# Redirecting to the newest page automatically

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

I'm making photo album pages in html. Each album has its own page such as `album01.html`, `album02.html`, `album03.html` etc.

I don't have a page named `album.html` (without number), but in some of my pages I want to use `<a href="album.html">Go to last page</a>` kind of buttons that will take visitor to the latest album all the time. For example, if the page with highest number is album15.html, I want all `<a href="album.html">` links to go to album15.html automatically.

What are the ways to do it without changing anything in the numbered album pages?

Comment: `.html` pages, haven't seen those in a while. Are `.html` pages parsed by PHP in your setup, since you tagged this with `php`? Why not link to `album15.html` instead? Why not make it more dynamic and use something like `album.php?page=15` etc?

Comment: You've tagged the question `.htaccess`. You could potentially do this using `.htaccess`, but not necessarily recommended - it's far from optimal since you would need to manually check the existence of each file (starting from some "maximum" number and working back until a file is found) and then issuing a redirect (or hardcode this number/filename in `.htaccess`). _Aside:_ You should also be using root-relative URLs, rather than relative to avoid potential future issues.

Comment: @brombeer Is it bad to have .html pages? I'm really asking because I'm a bit amateur in that subject. I'm able to design only in html+css+js. No idea about parsing, and its function. Please let me know what's wrong to publish the page in html format... Btw, I tagged this question with php and htaaccess only to indicate that I'm open for solutions with them too, if there's any

Comment: What you have is fine.  You just have to use some server-side language such as **php** in your album.html so that it keeps track of the last page or reads it from somewhere.  Or you can choose to update album.html manually.

Comment: @Rohit Gupta Thank you, how does this php part have to be? It might be the answer I need.

Comment: The PHP script would need to read the directory content (and filter for `albumXY.html` file, if you have other files in there as well), then sort the result by modification date (or creation? but usually one goes by modification) descending, and pick the first one. Your PHP code could either output the link dynamically; or you link to the PHP script to begin with, and then have that just return the content of the HTML file via `readfile`.